# In splunk addition of two same column from 2 indexes

Tags: splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

I have 2 indexes with one field(A) as common in both

Now I want the count of that same field(A) from both indexer in one panel .eg:

indexer 1= total event count of A=30
indexer 2= total event count of A=20

now in a panel i want to show total count of A as 50

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(index=ndxA OR index=ndxB) fieldA=*
| stats count(fieldA) as countA
```